# Why can a single be defined out-of-range?

Tags: vb.net

The range of single data type is `-3.4028235E+38` through `-1.401298E-45` for negative values. Why does this code **not** result in a compile time error?

```
'(Option Strict On)

Dim s As Single
s = -5.4028235E+38
```

Comment: The range of Single data type is

Comment: -3.4028235E+38 through -1.401298E-45 for negative values;

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: It is a valid question, but probably more about VB rules for conversion than about the implementation of Single.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer - The q is that it is smaller (out of range) and still compiles.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is converted from a Double to a Single, which results in `Single.NegativeInfinity`. If you would explicitly define the datatype like this (or with a `!`, [details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/constant-and-literal-data-types)):

```
s = -5.4028235E+38F
```

It would result in an overflow and wouldn't compile.

From the [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single?view=netframework-4.7.1) about conversions of the single data type:

> Double Narrowing: out-of-range values are converted to Double.NegativeInfinity or Double.PositiveInfinity.
>
> In addition, the Double values Double.NaN, Double.PositiveInfinity, and Double.NegativeInfinity covert to Single.NaN, Single.PositiveInfinity, and Single.NegativeInfinity, respectively.